# Unprotect sheet in MS Excel for ActiveX controls

Tags: excel, vba

I implemented smart dropdown (using Active X controls) in my sheet, so it is protected.
This functionality is not able to work because of protection.

When I right click on the sheet and Unprotect it, providing the password, it works.
I do not want the user to do this manually. I want that when user opens the sheet the sheet should get unprotected using VBA code.

The entire cells in the sheet are Locked (Format cells-> Protection -> Locked marked).
I cannot untick the Locked mark, as there are some validations which gets failed and not allow me to upload such template.

Below is an example as I cannot share the application code.

[image]

VBA code:

**In sheet1-> name of sheet is "tab0"**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick _
  (ByVal Target As Range, _
  Cancel As Boolean)
Dim str As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
```

[image]

Inside ThisWorkbook I have this

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    ThisWorkbook.UnProtect Password = "password" 
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be able to protect all cells in a sheet but not protect some. Select all cells, right click, format cells, protection tab, check locked. Select the cells you want the user to be able to edit, right click, format cells, protection tab, UNcheck locked. Then protect the sheet. The unlocked cells remain editable.

Comment: this is implemented, but still its not working

Comment: @garbb All cells are locked, and if I try to unlocked any of the cells and try to upload such template in application, then it gives error that "following cells are unlocked" there is certain validation on this template upload.

Comment: Put the code to unprotect the sheet inside `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` ?

Comment: @garbb yes  i have added Unprotect sheet code there as well

Comment: Someone else just posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428066/2806502) with unprotect code in workbook_open() and it worked for them

Comment: @garbb I have added this snippet in ThisWorkbook, well I am new to this. I dont know where it need to be added, still this is not working, can I change it to ThisWorkbook.Unprotect?
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     ActiveWorkBook.UnProtect Password = "password"
End Sub
And I want to unprotect the sheet. still it is not getting unprotected, after that i need to unlock the cells.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223308/discussion-between-kamini-and-garbb).

Comment: copy the code you have in `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` in your original question into `Workbook_Open`

Comment: @garbb will try and update

Comment: @garbb Tried in this way as well, but not able to get the smart drop down functionality work. whenever I click on sheet and see Unprotect Sheet option. when I Unprotect it manually then only the smart dropdown is working. :(

Answer (score 0):

A late input to this question:

I've been experiencing similar problems with Unprotecting sheets, and ended up doing aa fair bit of testing to find what works and what doesn't (always!).

The problem appears to be when assigning the sheet to an object and using the object's dot notation to unprotect e,g.:

```
'Setting the worksheet (globally) in sub Main()
Public goXsTT As Worksheet                      
    Set goXsTT = goXbWb.Sheets(2)

'Somewhere else in the code
    goXsTT.Unprotect

'This ***may*** fail, whereas:

    Sheets(2).Unprotect
'Works!
```

No idea why this is the case - just pointing out that it's a workaround if you're stumped, as I was. Hope it helps.  DG